# Control Dynamic text with a button, Flash CS5, AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I'm new to AS, especially AS3.

Here's the problem, I created a simple mouse-over interactivity using AS2, and I want to change it to AS3.

On the stage, I have several instances of a button, instance1, instance2, …. I also have a dynamic text box with instance name "txt_box". The initial text in the box reads "Initial Text".

On mousing over each button instance, the dynamic text changes depending on the instance. Let's say, it changes to description1, description2, ….

To do that, I attached the following code to the button instances (the code below is for instance1):

```
on (rollOver) {
txt_box.text = "Description1.";
}
on (rollOut) {
txt_box.text = "Initial Text";
}
```

So simple in AS2. How can I do that in AS3?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming ***Btn*** to be an instance of a movieclip containing a textbox named **txt_box**, Use:

```
Btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, mouse_over);

Btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, mouse_out);


function mouse_over(event:MouseEvent):void {

        Btn.txt_box.text = "Description";

        }

function mouse_out(event:MouseEvent):void {

        Btn.txt_box.text = "Initial Text";

        }
```

Comment: seems fine to me - though i'll add that you can't use "." to search out children in buttons (at least if they're `SimpleButtons`) - you need to search in the `upState` etc. I think in the question though, the textfield isn't associated with the buttons, just changed by them

Comment: Thanks, corrected it. Actually by button I meant was a movieclip, which was to be used as a custom button.

Comment: This would just change the dynamic text box into an MC that works as a button. This is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: But you gave me an idea! I can change the text box an MC with different labels. Each label will have a static text box of the appropriate description. When I roll over the buttons on the main timeline, I can send the playhead to the appropriate label in the text box MC. It's much much longer than what I had in AS2, but it should work. Thanks.

Comment: You can simply use an array of strings rather than separate keyframes. Also, please click on the tick mark if the answer helped you.